# Is there a difference between 평일 and 주중?

Tags: word-choice

I want to say something like "I work on weekdays" in Korean, but I can't decide on whether to use 평일 or 주중 (e.g. 나 **평일**에 일해 vs 나 **주중**에 일해). I've tried googling it; some answers from [this site](https://hinative.com/ko/questions/1955704) claim that 주중 is not an officially recognized word, while other answers from the same site define 평일 as any workday and 주중 as any weekday. Yet another answer states that 주중 includes all days of a certain week (이번 주중에 줄게 = I'll give it to you *sometime this week*).

[This answer](https://www.italki.com/question/301992?hl=ko) also seems to say that 평일 is any day that is not a rest day (like weekends or public holidays), while 주중 is any weekday. However, it is a stretch to call any of these answers well-researched, and the number of varying opinions intrigued me to search for a more definitive answer.

From a practical, day-to-day use standpoint, how accurate are these definitions? Is it fine to interchange the two words?

Comment: I think "이번 주중에 줄게 = I'll give it to you sometime this week" is a more accurate use of 주중,

Comment: @user17915 indeed, it would not do to say 이번 평일에...that is like nails on the chalkboard.  This is because a *week* takes 7 days to cycle, but a *business day* cycles in 24 hours...and in either language the 24 hour period from now is simply, "tomorrow" (or if you must, "Monday", right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases: **Business days = 평일 = 주중 = Monday to Friday**.

평일 or 주중 indicate working days, in general.

1. 나는 평일에만 (주중에만) 일해 I work only from Monday to Friday

(Surely, this implies that I do not work on holidays. This is a generality.)

2. 이번 주중에 줄께 I will give something this week

(Here 주중 does not include weekends. On weekends, we go
somewhere for a break. But if 주중 included weekends, then we would have to stay home.)

*Though the exact meaning may vary, I am referencing how it is typically used.*

Comment: this is the right answer